# htaccess: hide folder and hide file extention in link of subfolders

Tags: .htaccess

i have these folder stucture:

```
domain.com/pages/index.php
domain.com/pages/about/a-page.php
domain.com/pages/service/service-type/service-name.php
```

and i want them to be like:

```
domain.com/index
domain.com/about/a-page
domain.com/service/service-type/service-name
```

---

these is what i have so far:

```
#remove folder name on link e.g. https://example.com/pages/file.php will become https://example.com/file.php 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ pages/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/$1

#remove php file extension-e.g. https://example.com/file.php will become https://example.com/file 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

i honestly just copied this from a tutorial.. and tried other suggestions of similar problem as mine and these is somehow the closest i can get to my goal.

Answer (score 0):

after watching lots of htaccess tutorial, i found out that its supposed to be

```
RewriteEngine On

#remove php file extension-e.g. https://example.com/file.php will become https://example.com/file 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L] 

#remove folder name on link e.g. https://example.com/pages/file.php will become https://example.com/file.php 
RewriteRule ^$ pages/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/$1 [NC,L]
```

so i should have not forgot the [L] part at the rewrite rule to that it wont read the other rewrite conditions that are not meant for it.